# Trouble using Pine-Script timestamp() function with strategy.entry()

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to create a trade at a specific day/time but for some reason the trade is getting created 1 hour too late. It's supposed to be entered at 18:00, but is being entered at 19:00

In my example code below, using the exact same timestamp format as I use in the stretegy.entry and exit code, the label.new is correctly created at the specified time of 05 Aug 2021 03:00:00 UTC-7
But the strategy.entry is created 1 hour too late.
Does anyone know why this might be happening?
I know I could "fix" this issue by setting the time to UTC-6, but that would of course be just a hack :[Here is an screenshot showing my issue, as you can see in the Strategy summary, the entry was incorrectly added at 19:00 instead of 18:00][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugppo.png)

```
//@version=4
strategy("My Script", currency=currency.USD, max_boxes_count = 500, max_lines_count = 500,pyramiding = 100, overlay=true)

entryTime = timestamp("05 Aug 2021 18:00:00 UTC-7")
strategy.entry(id="Long", long=strategy.long, when=(time == entryTime))
strategy.exit(id="Long Exit", from_entry="Long", limit=110.076, stop=109.676, when=(time == entryTime))

entryTime := timestamp("05 Aug 2021 03:00:00 UTC-7")
if (time == entryTime)
    labeltext = tostring(entryTime)
    label.new(bar_index, high, text = "05 Aug 2021 03:00:00 UTC-7")
```

Comment: Please consider [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) your question to help understand it better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`label.new` function is plotting label immediately after condition was met. `strategy.entry()` function works differently  [[1]](http://%20https://www.tradingview.com/chart/?solution=43000619439):

> By default, a strategy is calculated once per bar, on the bar close.
> During that calculation, the strategy is able to generate new orders
> or update existing ones. But when the bar has already closed, it
> cannot be traded anymore, so the earliest moment that a strategy order
> can be filled is at the open of the next bar. Because of this, by
> default, the strategy will open a position one bar after the entry
> condition has been met.

Comment: Ah yes, ok. Thank you!